# Plot locations from array to map as multiple annotations

Tags: ios, arrays, json, mapkit, mkannotation

I am new to ios programming, I am trying to plot multiple locations on a mapview as annotations.

The closest I have been able to do is to get the locations from a server and put them on a table and then putting them on the table individually by clicking on the location i want to view.

My question is: I already have the json elements in an array as locations which is shown below, but I can't plot the locations on the map as multiple annotations, so I am trying to skip having to use a table and go from array to mapview. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

```
// HomeModel.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol HomeModelProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items;

@end

@interface HomeModel : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<HomeModelProtocol> delegate;

- (void)downloadItems;

@end
```

This is the class where the locations are downloaded and put in an array

```
// HomeModel.m

#import "HomeModel.h"
#import "Location.h"

@interface HomeModel()
{
   NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation HomeModel

- (void)downloadItems
{
NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://random.name/service.php"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse         *)response
{
_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData   options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

// Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to questions array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
    newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"Name"];
    newLocation.address = jsonElement[@"Address"];
    newLocation.latitude = jsonElement[@"Latitude"];
    newLocation.longitude = jsonElement[@"Longitude"];

    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}

// Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
if (self.delegate)
{
    [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
}
}
@end
```

This is the class where the array is put into a table

```
//ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
HomeModel *_homeModel;
NSArray *_feedItems;
Location *_selectedLocation;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.listTableView.delegate = self;
self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

_feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];    
_homeModel = [[HomeModel alloc] init];    
_homeModel.delegate = self;    
[_homeModel downloadItems];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{    
// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems = items;    
[self.listTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
// Retrieve cell
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];    
Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];    
myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;    
return myCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedLocation = _feedItems[indexPath.row];    
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;    
detailVC.selectedLocation = _selectedLocation;
}
@end
```

This is the class that takes the results from the table and posts it on the map view.

```
//DetailViewController.m

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D poiCoodinates;
poiCoodinates.latitude = [self.selectedLocation.latitude doubleValue];
poiCoodinates.longitude= [self.selectedLocation.longitude doubleValue];

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(poiCoodinates, 750, 750);

[self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

MKPointAnnotation *pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
pin.coordinate = poiCoodinates;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store your multiple MKPointAnnotations in an array and add that annotations array to mapview with [addAnnotations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/addAnnotations:) method.

```
NSMutableArray* annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];
    MKPointAnnotation* marker = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    marker.title = jsonElement[@"Name"];
    marker.subtitle = jsonElement[@"Address"];
    marker.coordinate.latitude = jsonElement[@"Latitude"];
    marker.coordinate.longitude = jsonElement[@"Longitude"];
    [annotations addObject:marker];
}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:markerArray];
```

Comment: hi, as i said, i am very new to ios programming. After downloading the data from the server then parse the JSON, i should loop through the JSON with your code and store the loations in a mkpointannotations array which i can then add to mapiew?